# Script with an average of 9s per execution, delivering 145s per execution

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

This script in GAS when I created it earlier today, testing gave an average of 9s per execution:

```
function ProjetoNovasLigas() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getRange('Página1!I2:N').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!P2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!Z2:Z').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!S2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!Y2:Y').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!U2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Página1!A2').setFormula('=TEXT(NOW(),"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm")');
  ss.getRange('Página1!A2').copyTo(ss.getRange('Página1!A2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

When enable it to run every 10 minutes via [script.google.com](https://script.google.com/) automatic trigger, it takes 145s to fully run:

[image]

Is there anything in the script that is wrong and that is making it happen? I would like a help, I will leave the spreadsheet here in case anyone wants to take a look at what may be happening:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15T4UPVtEHv43DLomKcTmdaPuGWMsBUoO7bLvlOhab4k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you're just copy pasting values, use `setValues()` instead. Also, directly set `new Date()`  instead of going through formulae.

Comment: @TheMaster I copied the script to ask it, updated it now. Could you show me the changes I need to make and what the script would look like? I confess that I have a little difficulty making changes, I learned a lot but without taking classes, it was just reading on the internet with ready-made programming lines and help here through the stackoverflow. If you can help me, I would be very grateful.

Comment: The real problem with specifying ranges like you have in your question is that you get nulls from the bottom of you data all the way to maxrows.  Run this little function and look at the logs. `function test() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange('A1:A');
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  Logger.log(vA);
}` You could probably still do the code the way you have it and change the way to specify ranges to `getRange(row,column,number of rows, number of columns)` and still  get reasonable performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to speed up execution by batching up operations using [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#setValues(Object)) and array manipulation.

#### Sample Script:

```
function archivr() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Página1');
  var lr = sh.getLastRow();
  var values = sh.getRange('I2:Z' + lr).getValues();
  values.forEach(function(row){
    row.push("", row[16]); //[16] = Col Y; Move Col Y to the right of Col Z
    row.splice(6, 11);//Remove Col N to Col Y
  });
  sh.getRange(2,12, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values); //set modified values to Col P
  sh.getRange('A2').setValue(new Date());
}
```

#### References:

- [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [Best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: Thank you very much, there were flaws in this format, ended up relocating the data to the wrong places, but now I understand how it works and I will edit it to correct these flaws.